# how to fetch ER diagram for DB2 datawarehouse using schemacrawler

Tags: schemacrawler

i m using db2 data warehouse. I am using schemacrawler to fetch the ER diagram.
In my data warehouse PK and FK are not mentioned. So I want to ask that can we add PK and FK through Schemacrawler to fetch the ER diagram.
I have read weak-associations functionality, but its working if primary is present into DB.
IF primary key is also not present then how to use SchemaCrawler on data warehouse to fetch the ER diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a Catalog Attributes file with relationship definitions](https://www.schemacrawler.com/attributes.html). These will show up in the diagram.